# page.scss not applying to my page.html on my ionic page

Tags: css, ionic-framework, sass

I'm trying to make a table with flexbox on my ionic page using SASS, for some reason the code I've written on the .scss file is not applying to the page.html. Any idea?

**page html:**

```
<head>

          <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
          <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
   <h2>Row oriented table</h2>
      <div class="Rtable Rtable--4cols">

        <div class="Rtable-cell"><h3>Eddard Stark</h3></div>
        <div class="Rtable-cell">Has a sword named Ice</div>
        <div class="Rtable-cell">No direwolf</div>
        <div class="Rtable-cell"><strong>Lord of Winterfell</strong></div>

        <div class="Rtable-cell"><h3>Jon Snow</h3></div>
        <div class="Rtable-cell">Has a sword named Longclaw</div>
        <div class="Rtable-cell">Direwolf: Ghost</div>
        <div class="Rtable-cell"><strong>Knows nothing</strong></div>

        <div class="Rtable-cell"><h3>Arya Stark</h3></div>
        <div class="Rtable-cell">Has a sword named Needle</div>
        <div class="Rtable-cell">Direwolf: Nymeria</div>
        <div class="Rtable-cell"><strong>No one</strong></div>

      </div>
</body
```

**PAGE.SCSS:**

```
             page-ficha-atual {
            $bw: 3px;  // border width

            .Rtable {
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            margin: 0 0 3em 0;
            padding: 0;
            }
            .Rtable-cell {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            flex-grow: 1;
            width: 100%;  // Default to full width
            padding: 0.8em 1.2em;
            overflow: hidden; // Or flex might break
            list-style: none;
            border: solid $bw white;
            background: fade(slategrey,20%);
            > h1, > h2, > h3, > h4, > h5, > h6 { margin: 0; }
            }


            .Rtable--2cols > .Rtable-cell  { width: 50%; }
            .Rtable--3cols > .Rtable-cell  { width: 33.33%; }
            .Rtable--4cols > .Rtable-cell  { width: 25%; }
            .Rtable--5cols > .Rtable-cell  { width: 20%; }
            .Rtable--6cols > .Rtable-cell  { width: 16.6%; }



            html { 
            height: 100%;
            background-color: #EEE; 
            }
            body {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            min-height: 100%;
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding: 2em;
            max-width: 800px;
            font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
            font-size: 1.2em;
            background-color: white;
            border: double 3px #DDD;
            border-top: none; border-bottom: none;
            }
            h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { margin-top: 0; }
            h3 { font-size: 1.2em; }
            h4 { font-size: 1em; }
            strong { color: darken(slategrey,20%); }

                 }
```

The output is only the text inside the div `class="Rtable-cell"`'s. Any ideas why this is happening? Is it a conflict with bootstrap that I'm also using in the page?

Update: The issue seemed to be that I need the scss code inside page-selector { }. But didn't change after that.
edit: The sass is working, just to make sure i created a sass variable at theme/variables/scss. And called it inside my page.scss, it worked

Comment: Can you provide a snippet of this in action?

Comment: Dumb question, where is the scss file getting loaded?

Comment: Good question, im not sure, i created the page via ionic CLI, that creates a folder with 3 files inside, page.ts ,page.html, page.scss. I thought ionic loaded it automatically

Answer (score 0):

**You can't have a link to SCSS File in your HTML page**. You have to compile it down to CSS First. Another thing, check that the code provided you have wrong the closure of the `</head>` and `</body>`

I recommend reading the entire documentation:
http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html

Keep rocking!

Comment: The link is for bootstrap not for the scss file, i was expecting the ionic to auto import the scss file into the html page, since i created it via CLI. Maybe the problem is that the code is on SASS and the file is SCSS, i thought it was the same thing, ill read about converting from one to another

Answer (score 0):

You're not closing your head tag properly. It needs to look like this:

```
<head>

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>


</head>
```

Comment: I edited it, it wasnt like that in the code, not really the problem =/.

Comment: Ok where are you compiling your sass? I see no reference to an output here in your HTML.

Comment: Im pretty sure ionic does that by default. I created a sass variables in the theme/variables.scss , and called it inside p{ } on the page.scss, and it worked..